# How to change the mako substitution delimiter characters?

Tags: python, html, templates, pyramid, mako

Is it possible to change the "delimiter tags" for expression substitution in the Python Mako templating library? If so, how?

**e.g.:** Instead of `<div>${foobar}</div>`, I would like to use the syntax `<div>{{foobar}}</div>`.

I can't seem to find any references in [the Mako docs](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/syntax.html#expression-substitution).

Comment: Apparently, it's not currently possible: https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/mako/issue/235/rearchitect-the-parser-to-be-more-modern

Comment: @Raj Thanks! Good to know! ...you can post that as an answer if you want, since it *is* the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of March 6, 2015, it's **not currently possible**.

See [the feature request](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/mako/issue/235/rearchitect-the-parser-to-be-more-modern) to add configurable delimiters for Mako.